# How to Convert unicode sequence to utf8 in php which received from json android?

Tags: php, json, unicode

I have receive json data in php from android an just get sequence of unicode chracaters:

```
\u0628\u0647\u0645\u0646
```

How can I convert it to utf8 by the way characters are arabic character.

Comment: Please post the json string.

Comment: Isn't JSON already in Unicode? Looks like whatever you're getting is not a JSON string. You can convert the numbers to Unicode chars using `<? echo "\u{0628}\u{0647}\u{0645}\u{0646}"; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Just use [json_decode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '{
    "Arabic": "\u0628\u0647\u0645\u0646"
}';

$json_decode = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($json_decode);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Arabic] => بهمن
)
```

Comment: I sent my code, I use this but there is no change still.